# подключить Visualizer

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

Пытаюсь подключить класс Visualizer

```
    mPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music);
    mPlayer.start();
    Visualizer visualizer = new Visualizer(mPlayer.getAudioSessionId());
```

Звук появляется, и сразу ошибка:
Cannot initialize Visualizer engine, error: -3

Comment: А если вместо `mPlayer.getAudioSessionId()` передать `0`?

Comment: та же самая ошибка @ЮрийСПб

Comment: Согласно [этому примеру](http://android-er.blogspot.ru/2015/02/create-audio-visualizer-for-mediaplayer.html) создавать `Visualizer` надо до старта. И добавить ещё и `visualizer.setEnabled(true);`

Comment: скопировал пример, запустил - та же ошибка. Может быть проблема в эмуляторе? @ЮрийСПб

Comment: Не, не эмулятор. У меня на девайсе тоже падает(